# Customizing shared components in Angular

Tags: angular

I was told to make several tags for all the shared components in the Angular app, so it is possible to make instant changes and for better management. So the page will mainly include these components, like:

```
<cx-card>
  <cx-lbl>Some text</cx-lbl>
  <cx-btn>Click Me</cx-btn>
</cx-card>
```

My questions are:

1. Components work fine when alone, but the label/button doesn't appear when inside the card. How can I fix it?
2. By default, my components are empty (only design is preset). But in the example above, both "Some text" and "Click Me" don't appear. How to make it possible?

Some real examples should be perfect, but even a link to some reference will be helpful. Thank you in advance! Sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take advantage of the `ng-content` tag. This projects the content inside of the tag into the component itself.

So the HTML of your `cx-card` component could be.

```
<div class="cx-card">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Now whatever is between `<cx-card>...</cx-card>` will appear where you placed the `ng-content` tag in your `cx-card` component's HTML.

Same thing goes for the `cx-label` and `cx-btn`. Use `ng-content` in their HTML to present `Some Text` and `Click Me`. For this, you can take advantage of the `@Input` property of each component as well. Something like so:

In `cx-label` component TS:

```
@Input() text: string;
....HTML...
<div class="cx-label">{{text}}</div>
....HTML where it is used....
<cx-lbl [text]="'Some text'"></cx-label>
```

And in `cx-btn` component:

```
@Input() text: string;
...HTML...
<div class="cx-btn">{{text}}</div>
...HTML where it is used...
<cx-btn [text]="'Click Me'"></cx-btn>
```

I personally would do `@Input` for the button and label and `ng-content` for the `cx-card`.

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/ (Real deep dive into `ng-content`).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. I will also check the link you've shared.